# API Not Returning Data Despite 200OK Response in GetStaticProps()

Tags: reactjs, json, next.js

I need to make an axios.get request to an API for getStaticProps() in  next.

The response is being set successfully and returns a 200OK,  however, the data is nowhere to be found in the response.

Where can you find the data?

The Data gets returned perfectly in Postman.

Here is the getStaticProps():

```
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const config = {
    headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer xxxxxxx'}
  }

  const res = await axios.get('https://wookie.codesubmit.io/movies', config)

  console.log(res)

  return {
    props: { }
  }
}
```

This is the response:

Response:

```
Response {
  [Symbol(realm)]: null,
  [Symbol(state)]: {
    aborted: false,
    rangeRequested: false,
    timingAllowPassed: true,
    requestIncludesCredentials: true,
    type: 'default',
    status: 200,
    timingInfo: {
      startTime: 1395217.8387000002,
      redirectStartTime: 0,
      redirectEndTime: 0,
      postRedirectStartTime: 1395217.8387000002,
      finalServiceWorkerStartTime: 0,
      finalNetworkResponseStartTime: 0,
      finalNetworkRequestStartTime: 0,
      endTime: 0,
      encodedBodySize: 16195,
      decodedBodySize: 16195,
      finalConnectionTimingInfo: null
    },
    cacheState: '',
    statusText: 'OK',
    headersList: HeadersList {
      [Symbol(headers map)]: [Map],
      [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
    },
    urlList: [ [URL] ],
    body: { stream: undefined }
  },
  [Symbol(headers)]: HeadersList {
    [Symbol(headers map)]: Map(6) {
      'server' => 'nginx/1.12.2',
      'date' => 'Thu, 02 Feb 2023 10:10:39 GMT',
      'content-type' => 'application/json',
      'content-length' => '21138',
      'connection' => 'keep-alive',
      'access-control-allow-origin' => '*'
    },
    [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
  }
}
undefined
Response {
  [Symbol(realm)]: null,
  [Symbol(state)]: {
    aborted: false,
    rangeRequested: false,
    timingAllowPassed: true,
    requestIncludesCredentials: true,
    type: 'default',
    status: 200,
    timingInfo: {
      startTime: 1470362.2073,
      redirectStartTime: 0,
      redirectEndTime: 0,
      postRedirectStartTime: 1470362.2073,
      finalServiceWorkerStartTime: 0,
      finalNetworkResponseStartTime: 0,
      finalNetworkRequestStartTime: 0,
      endTime: 0,
      encodedBodySize: 16195,
      decodedBodySize: 16195,
      finalConnectionTimingInfo: null
    },
    cacheState: '',
    statusText: 'OK',
    headersList: HeadersList {
      [Symbol(headers map)]: [Map],
      [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
    },
    urlList: [ [URL] ],
    body: { stream: undefined }
  },
  [Symbol(headers)]: HeadersList {
    [Symbol(headers map)]: Map(6) {
      'server' => 'nginx/1.12.2',
      'date' => 'Thu, 02 Feb 2023 10:11:54 GMT',
      'content-type' => 'application/json',
      'content-length' => '21138',
      'connection' => 'keep-alive',
      'access-control-allow-origin' => '*'
    },
    [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
  }
}
undefined
```

Postman Request (Removed Token for obvious reasons):

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? What response do you get? Can you post response status and body? I don't think your problem is related to `getStaticProps`

Comment: See response in edit

Comment: It seems that the API is returning `200 OK`, so `Authorization` header is being properly sent

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(res.data)` (see [response schema](https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema))?

Comment: res.data returns undefined

Comment: Please show the working postman request. If the request works there, something has to be different ... And have you checked the response in the developer tools of the browser? Does it contain a response body? But the content-length header of 21138 would suggest there should be a body ...

Comment: See edits - I cant see the response in developer tools

Comment: The interesting part would be the request headers and the response headers in postman. Can you see any error in the browser console? And what do you mean by "you can't see the response in developertools"? The developer tools will show all requests the browser made together with their response (or do you just mean the body). If you don'T see the body in the developer tools there is none ...

Comment: No error in browser console. See edits for headers. As for Developer Tools - I had a look in  Network but tbh dont know exactly what im looking for there. . .

Comment: Are you sending a BODY with you GET request (see the green dot in the body request)?? And what is that `Application` header doing there? You don't have that in your axios request ...

Comment: They make no difference - I sent them again with no BODY  and removed those headers and same result

Comment: Well, then you would have to learn how to use the browsers' developer tools and search for that request and it's response there. Typically I'd say for requests that work in postman but not with ajax requests, it's a CORS issue. But there is a Allow-Origin: * header present and you say there is no error in the console ...

Comment: Nice try, but the answer was much simpler than that haha

Answer (score -1):

```
export const getStaticProps = async () => {

  const config = {
    headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer Wookie2021'}
  }

const res = await fetch('https://wookie.codesubmit.io/movies', config)

const data = await res.json()

console.log(data)


return {
  props: {
    data
  }
}
}
```

console.log(res) wasn't returning the data because there was no await in front of it. Easy mistake to make.

Comment: You notice you are using a complete different library than in your orignal question, don't you? `fetch !== axios` and they behave totally different with respect to returning the data ...

Comment: No, I was completely unaware that axios and fetch were different until you told me just now.